# Can you suggest me a fast Swing IDE

Tags: java, user-interface, swing, netbeans

Currently I am using Netbeans to develop applications in Swing, but Netbeans is very very slow. Can anyone suggest me a comprehensive Swing development GUI like Netbeans but lightweight

Thanks

Comment: Slow?  You have enough memory?

Comment: NetBeans is definitely much slower than say, Visual Studio, at least for my setup, but I found that using the latest JDK, latest NetBeans version (only sets up required dependencies), enough RAM, and most importantly... a SSD does wonders for it ;-)

Comment: NetBeans works very fast on my humble home computer - and I have no SSD. It's certainly one of the fastest Java IDE's - almost as fast as Eclipse and way faster than IntelliJ IDEA... And it consumes next to none RAM when compared with IDEA...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Programmatically: [MigLayout](http://www.miglayout.com/)

Visually: [jVider](http://www.jvider.com/)

Comment: Thank you, MigLayout looks promising.. have already started digging it!!

Answer (score 1):

You can also have a look at [JFormDesigner](http://www.jformdesigner.com).